# error call to member function

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I login in I am trying to set up some user activity for codeigniter project so can see which users logs on and off.

On my **library function login** I have this data here below **But now throws error** Not sure on how to fix it.

```
$activity_data = array(
'user_id' => $this->CI->session->userdata('user_id'),
'name' => $this->CI->session->userdata('firstname') . ' ' . $this->CI->session->userdata('lastname')
);

$this->CI->load->model('admin/common/user_login_model');
// Error Here Line 27
$this->user_login_model->addActivity('login', $activity_data);
```

Error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: User::$user_login_model
Filename: libraries/User.php
Line Number: 27
Fatal error: Call to a member function addActivity() on a non-object in C:\Xampp\htdocs\codeigniter-cms\application\libraries\User.php on line 27
```

**On Model**

```
public function addActivity($key, $data) {
  $data['user_id'] = $this->user->getID();

  if (isset($data['user_id'])) {
     $user_id = $data['user_id'];
  } else {
     $user_id = 0;
  }

  $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . $this->db->dbprefix . "user_activity` SET 
     `user_id` = '" . (int)$user_id . "', 
     `key` = " . $this->db->escape($key) . ", 
     `data` = " . $this->db->escape(serialize($data)) . ", 
     `ip` = " . $this->db->escape($this->input->server('REMOTE_ADDR')) . ", 
     `date_added` = NOW()
  ");
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you made an instance of CI and loaded the model into it. Yet, you try to access the model directly from the library class with `$this->user_login_model`, which is wrong. Try instead :

```
$this->CI->user_login_model->addActivity('login', $activity_data);
```